# A game I did not purchase appears on my Switch library

Tags: technical-issues, nintendo-switch, nintendo-eshop

In my Switch games library, there is a game that I do not own, both digitally and physically, that shows up in the "See more games" page.

- The icon when I hover the game is the cloud download icon (not the missing Switch cartridge icon). As if I had deleted it and was downloadable from the eshop.
- When I open that game's page on the eshop, it says I do not own it and I can purchase it.
- It does not appear in my transaction history.

The game is *Assassin's Creed - The Ezio Collection*. I do own *Assassin's Creed - the Rebel Collection* digitally. I wonder if that's what created the bug?

Comment: Sometimes, games will be given away freely (or gifted) under certain conditions. Think of the example where Skyrim Special Edition was given away for free to everyone who owned the original Skyrim plus all DLC's. However, I don't know enough about switch to answer this question.

Comment: My curiosity is getting the better of me... What happens if you click it? As for the answer: I wonder if maybe those two games have, by a screw up, the same ID and so the game is The rebel collection, but when it queries the servers for the thumbnail art/title it gives the ezio collection

Comment: @Fredy31 clicking on it opens the eshop to that game's page.

Comment: Some advertising probably